# Jquery validation: submit the form with javascript with no validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

i'm just using the JQuery validation plugin.
i have the following spec: 'if the form isn't used in 10 seconds, give the user a warning, if he doesn't do anything, submit it anyway'

besides the timer etc. i have this code to submit the form:

```
timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {

$("#session_expired").val("true");
$("form:first").validate({
                    onsubmit: false
                });
$("form:first").submit();
}, 10000);
```

what it does: it sets a certain hidden field value and then it submits the form. I've added the validate function to make sure it doesn't validate in this case.
Bu you might have guessed it: it doesn't work.

Anyone any clue?

Michel

Comment: good one :) it doesn't submit, it still marks all the required fields with no value as 'invalid' and it doesn't submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the DOM method directly instead of jQuery submit method for the submit:

Replace

```
$("form:first").submit();
```

with:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

My guess is that:

```
$("form:first").validate({ onsubmit: false });
```

only applies to when the form is submited by a submit button push.

Comment: i THINK that is a good guess (i'm not sure) but i KNOW this works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would remove each part of the function and then test it until I can find which part of the function is a failing. Also us firebug and console.log to trace what is happening within the function. e.g.

```
timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
console.log('timeout')
}, 10000);
```

Comment: it does fire the function ($("form:first").submit();) after 10 seconds, but the validation doesn't 'stop' so i'm thinking maybe the 
$("form:first").validate({                    onsubmit: false                });
isn't correct